# Position img outside container but within row in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-image

I have a page with the normal Bootstrap set up `.container > .row > .col`. I'd like to have a picture next to my `col-6` column that "break out" of the container, but that is within the row (basically full-width container) because the text in the column needs to be vertically aligned to the middle in regard to the image.

The picture that depicts what I need:

[image]

The reason I don't work with background-image for the container is because of the positioning. I don't want the picture to slide behind de text.

Many "How it works" pages have a similar setup, for example https://setapp.com/?utm_medium=affiliate+program&utm_source=43&utm_campaign=macpaw.com

Comment: You could position the img with regular ol css

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. This would be the last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put a `display: flex;` and `align-items: centre;` on the row.

see https://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-center-flexbox

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer. i use display flex, however, it doesn’t address my question.